# Trying to setup component redirection behavior in React web app

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

**Scenario:**

I am developing a React web app in which I have 4 components.

1. Header
2. Landing
3. Home
4. AccessDenied

The `Header` component is the one which is common for `Landing` and `Home`. When application is run, the first component user sees is `Landing` which has no crucial functionality. It has only an image and header component.

When user clicks on `Sign In` in header component, upon successful sign in the component is redirected from `Landing` to `Home`.

In `Home` component in `useEffect()` hook, I try to call MS Graph API to obtain active directory group information in which the signed in user belongs (since the Graph API asks user access token in authorization header). If the group information is returned that ensures user is registered under that group otherwise the user is redirect to `AccessDenied` component.

**Challenge:**

The `AccessDenied` component has a user friendly message and a button to redirect user back to `Landing` page. To do this redirection, I applied `useNavigate` hook. This hook normally works, but not in this scenario. When I click on the button, it just refreshes the `AccessDenied` component.

My suspicion is around `useEffect()` hook. Suggestions are welcome.

*Please suggest or provide ideas to overcome this challenge. If there is any information missed, let me know and I can update the detail.*

**Below is the code for each component that I have implemented**

**header.jsx**

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useMsal } from '@azure/msal-react';

export const Header = () => {
    const { instance } = useMsal();
     const handleLoginRedirect = async () => {
          await instance.loginRedirect();    
     };

    const handleLogoutRedirect = () => {
            instance.logoutRedirect();   
    };

    return (
    <>
        <Link onClick={handleLogoutRedirect}>Sign out</Link>
        <Link onClick={handleLoginRedirect}>Sign in</Link>
        </>
    );
};
```

**Landing.jsx**

```
const Landing = () => {
return (
    <>
        <div style={{ textAlign: 'center', margin: '20px', fontSize: '32px' }}>
            Welcome to demo site.
        </div>
    </>
    );
};

export default Landing;
```

**Home.jsx**

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'; 
import { Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useMsal } from '@azure/msal-react';  

const Home = () => {     
  const { accounts } = useMsal();     
  const [userMembership, setUserMembership] = useState([]);     
  const groupId = 'f83c1f45-8ca9-4ac3-9e2a-0c6df2381589'; 
  const navigate = useNavigate();     
  
  useEffect(() => {         
    const isLoggedIn = accounts.length > 0;         
    if (isLoggedIn) {             
      fetchData();         
    }               
    if (userMembership === null) {             
      navigate('/AccessDenied');         
    } else {             
      //render the page content         
    }     
  }, [])      
  
  const fetchData = async () => {         
    try {             
      const graphApi = `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/memberOf/microsoft.graph.group?$count=true&$filter=id eq '${groupId}'`;                          
      const result = await instance.acquireTokenSilent({                 
        account: accounts[0],                 
        scopes: loginRequest.scopes,             
      });                  
      
      const response = await fetch(graphApi , {                 
        scopes: graphConfig.scopes,                 
        headers: {                     
          Authorization: `Bearer ${result.accessToken}`                 
        },             
      });             
      
      if (response.ok) {                 
        const data = await response.json();                 
        **setUserMembership(data);**                 
        return data.value;             
      } else {                 
        console.error('Failed to fetch data from graph api:', response.statusText);             
      }         
    } catch (error) {             
      console.error('Error fetching data from graph api:', error);             
      throw error;         
    } 
  };

   return (
    <> 
     <p>the content on home page</p>
    </>
    );
  };

  export default Home;
```

**AccessDenied.jsx**

```
const AccessDenied = () => 
{
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const handleClick = () => 
    {
        navigate('/Landing'); /* this should take user to Landing page but 
                                 this just refreshes*/
    }

    return (
        <>
          <div>
              <h2>Access Denied</h2>
              <p>Please request to obtain access.</p>
              <button onClick={handleClick}>Home</button>
          </div>
        </>
    );
}
export default AccessDenied;
```

**Note:** For user sign-in and sign-out in header component, I have used `MSAL` library. I have also specified this component's in `route`

Comment: According to your statements the Home component is never rendered from the moment the button is clicked (i.e. getting navigated to the Landing page)... Therefore the Home component's useEffect can never take place... You are going to want to look else where for this bug, it has nothing to do with the Home Component from what I can see. I'd suggest clicking on the button and seeing if the history is pushed twice... Or how many times it is pushed... But the Home component is not causing the problem based upon your statements.

Comment: @SharpDev, you seem very right. I checked by removing actual code from home.jsx where all useeffect call occurs and kept simple html with mere button click to redirect to accessdenied.jsx. From accessdenied.jsx to landing.jsx it does the redirection but goes to home.jsx in flick of second. Should my routing be the issue? Is there an alternative or optimal way to implement redirection other than useNavigate() ?